# Java File uploading - SocketException - Connection reset

Tags: java, rest, cxf, webclient, connection-reset

I am using apache.cxf webClient .I am trying to upload file in the post API and I am
trying to get the uploaded file path in the response. I am calling post method .

```
PostResponse response =webClient.post(attachments,PostResponse.class);
webClient.reset();
return response;
```

After getting the response I am returning the response to other method . In that method
I am just reading some values in the response.

```
String path=response.getPath();
```

Everything works fine. When the file size is less than 10 kb, I am able to upload the file
and I can read the path.

But when the size is around 500 kb , I am not able to upload the file .
I am getting Exception "SocketException - Connection reset".

I changed the client settings to

```
webClient.connection.timeout.msecs=600000
webClient.receive.timeout.msecs=600000
webClient.connection.keepalive=true
```

But this also didnt help me much .
I am suspecting the issue is with this line "webClient.reset();" . Is it so ?
After reseting client , we are not supposed to read from the response ? But this code is 
working when the file size is less. If this is the problem then Shall I make code changes 
like

```
webClient.reset();
//Set the end points all others here
PostResponse response =webClient.post(attachments,PostResponse.class);
return response;
```

If you suspecting any other reason for the connection issue , please let me know.
Thanks in advance .

Comment: The *server* clearly has an upload limit, and is closing the connection when it's exceed. Fiddling around at the client end isn't going to fix it.

Comment: @EJP Checked with server team , there is no limit in them

Comment: Get them to check their logs. They closed the connection for some reason. Why?

Comment: Yes they checked logs and saying like the error is @ client side .

Comment: It might be a good option to rule out a problem on the server (commented by @EJP). Could you send an attachment using a browser?